# Taylor Series expansion of an arbitrary function

Tags: c, matlab, taylor-series

I am trying to get the coefficients of the Taylor series expansion of arbitrary functions. The input function has to be in the form of variables, and the output has to contain only the coefficients.

I have tried some MATLAB functions like 'taylor', but they give the entire expansion in the form of an expression written in symbolic form. 
I know such a thing can be done in Mathematica, but I have no exposure to it. Therefore I am reluctant to use Mathematica to do it.

It'd be a great help if a MATLAB function can be suggested. A C/C++ library capable of doing the same will be equally helpful.

Edit: 
I need the coefficients of the Taylor series expansion of:
I need to find the coefficients of the Taylor series expansion of

f(x) = Product_from_{m=1}_to{M}[  {(1-2^{-m})z(1-p)} / {1-z+(1-2^(-m)z(1-p)} ].

Comment: Are you looking for polyfit?  Otherwise, show some sample code for what you want to input, and what you want the output to be.

Comment: No, I am not. I have edited my question to include how my function looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found a way:

Enter the function in the form of `syms`. And then use `taylor` to find the Taylor series expansion. After than use `sym2poly` to get the coefficients.

If anyone has a better method, please write your answers.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for [this function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fntlr.html)?

Comment: I have edited my question to include how my function looks like. Could you please tell me how to use 'fntlr' to find the coefficients of the Taylor series expansion of such kind of a function?